# Change height of control dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I am using Angular Js. I have a checkbox, on selection of it, I am showing an image. When the checkbox is unchecked, I want to reduce the height, so that image height is not taken.

I am using the below code, but the height is not reducing, when checkbox is unchecked.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px !important;">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="includeImage" ng-checked="true" ng-change="isImageInclude(includeImage)">Include Image
        </label>
        <img ng-src="{{seasonTypeImage_url}}" style="padding-left: 20px !important;height:40px" id="imgHolder" alt="image will display here." class="imagerowStyle" /> <br />
</div>
```

In css:

```
.imagerowStyle{
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
}
```

In controller.cs:

```
$scope.isImageInclude = function(includeImage) {
    if ($scope.includeImage) { //If it is checked
        $scope.seasonTypeImage_url = $scope.selectedseasonType.ImageUrl;
    } else {
        $scope.seasonTypeImage_url = _SeasonBaseUrl + "Images//no-imag.png";
        jQuery('#imgHolder').css({ height: "40px !important" });
    }
}
```

If any image is available, the width should not exceed 400px, and height should not exceed 150px. If no image is available, then height should not excced 40px.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you should use `ng-class` if you only want to influence the height. If you want to show or hide the image element since nothing is in there, you should use `ng-hide` or `ng-show`.

```
<img ng-src="{{seasonTypeImage_url}}" ng-class="includeImage ? 'big400' : 'small50'" />
```

We are cheching if includeImage is set to true and setting the class according to our needs.

And in your css:

```
.big400 {
  height: 400px;
}

.small50 {
  height: 50px;
}
```

There are of course several other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$('#imgHolder').css('height', '100px !important');
```

Comment: Please consider explaining the answer. Code-only answers are discouraged